# The most effective way how to store separated data in to database

Tags: asp.net, xml, database, text, web

The situation is like this:

- We have multiple websites where each of them contains random count of text blocks.
- We want to store the whole page content (all text blocks) into one column into database. In displaying process of html page we process the content from database and we separate it into text blocks

**What is the best way of storing those data?** 
The key point is read and process them as fast as possible. Storing and preprocessing isn't the key point.

**In my mind there are some possible ways:**

- Store data as XML
- Store data separated by a special char
- Store all texts blocks as one-many relation into database

**Any better suggestions?**

Comment: Or use a NoSQL storage...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer You mean something like direct storing into files?

Comment: this is the faster "Store data separated by a special char", or use a library that do the same like `protobuf-net`

Comment: Check Nadav's answer :D

Comment: @DavidHorák I gather he means something like MongoDB or Redis depending on your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good use case for a NoSQL document database.  The key question to ask is whether you'll have a requirement to process relational joins between these documents.

The document database approach would be to store the document, most likely as JSON (or perhaps XML or HTML).  You'd have a key that you could use to quickly access the document content, and it would be ready-to-go for your processor (if it's a JavaScript based processor, you probably want to store it in JSON; if there's little-to-no processing, store it as HTML/XML).

In this case, you have a group of documents about TV shows, and you'll only ever grab them by show (you'll never need to process whether a particular actor was in multiple shows and tell us which ones).

If, on the other hand, you need to normalize the data in some cases, or it will be helpful to do so in the future, go with a relational database.  You could simulate NoSQL there by storing documents in XML or JSON format, but you could also have columns that would have foreign key constraints (NoSQL has a harder time with this).

In this case, you'll have a group of documents with relational information, so that if you need to someday tell us about which TV shows an actor was in, you can do so more easily.

If you're still not sure, go with the relational approach.  It won't be quite as fast or trendy, but it will allow for future growth.

Answer (score 1):

**The key point is read and process them as fast as possible**

Sounds like somthing I would use NoSQL for.
Database like redis.

XML - when your xml file/s gets big you lose speed, which is your key point.